# What is $OPTIONS in a systemd service file?

Tags: systemd

I'm looking at the following line in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service` file on a Fedora 25 box:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS
```

I'm not sure where `$OPTIONS` comes from. It looks like an environment variable, although when I set a shell variable that way it is ignored, e.g.

```
# OPTIONS='-p 9999'
# systemctl start sshd
```

I read through the command lines portion of the systemd.service man page, which indicates that environment variables can be set via an `Environment` line:

```
Environment="ONE=one" 'TWO=two two'
```

However, no such OPTIONS variable is set there.

There is additionally an `EnvironmentFile` line, e.g.:

```
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/sshd
```

No `$OPTIONS` variable is set there either. To what does `$OPTIONS` refer, and how is it set?

Comment: Have you tried to set the env variable `export OPTIONS='-p 9999'` before the `systemctl start sshd`?

Comment: You can probably set it in the `EnvironmentFile`, but it's empty (doesn't exist) by default.

Comment: @MichaelD. Systemd would be pretty broken if it didn't start services in a clean environment. `invoke-rc.d` and `service` commands have always cleaned the environments, `systemd` is no different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unit file in Debian is similar, containing:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
```

Here, the EnvironmentFile assigns `SSHD_OPTS`:

```
# Options to pass to sshd
SSHD_OPTS=
```

It's likely that Fedora uses a similar system, but for some reason they just haven't explicitly set the variable. That shouldn't matter, it should expand to an empty string.

There's a mention [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/59011/how-to-use-options-variable-in-systemd-config-files/) that e.g. `httpd.service` uses `OPTIONS` similarly, and sets it in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`. So it's likely just unset for some reason.

You could check `sshd`'s command line with `ps` to see what the variable is expanded to, and also set it to something in the sysconfig file to check that it works if set there.

---

As for setting the environment variable on the shell command line, AFAIU systemd doesn't run the services in the environment of the shell calling `systemctl`, but forks them off the main systemd process. That way they don't inherit settings of the shell environment even accidentally. Environment variables can have a wide range of effects and it would be annoying to have your services act differently depending on if they are started at system boot or restarted from the command line.

That `$MAINPID` however, [it's special](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).